# externalize spring configuration and logs

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-batch

I need your help on two issues :

1// I have a spring batch app that has this application.properties file  :

```
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:xxxxxxxx
ClassApp=xxxx
Country=xxxxx
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
CRON_EXPRESSION=xxxxx
```

I want to externalize this configuration to an external file in a specific location and pass it then in the jvm when i run the final jar generated by my application.

Because the jar will be run on a centos machine later and all the variables in the properties file should get their values from that external file !!

How can i do this ?

2// Also, i have some log feature in my app like this one :

```
  log.debug("CreateQuartzJob is running......");
```

But i want to externalize application logs to an external file also with all execution details too.

How can i make these two features pleaaase ?

Thank you for help :)

Comment: You can explore Spring Config which can run as an external service.  
Also, it can be a file hosted somewhere and you can fetch it.
Or it can be stored in DB as values

Comment: Have you read [the documenation on externalizing configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config)? Basically that is all supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Sid And how do i call variables in the code? For example when the variable is declared in app.properties i call it this way : @Value("${Country}") private String Country;

Comment: @M.Deinum can't find the external config part in the doc

Comment: What do you think the link I added to the comment goes to?

Comment: @M.Deinum at first it leads to main reference and cannot find external configuration then i found it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As for external configuration, you can use the "additional-location" argument when running your application. Just create a properties or yaml file, e.g., application.yml, and run your jar like this:

> java -jar myJar.jar
> --spring.config.additional-location=file:/some/directory/application.yml

Comment: And how do i call variables in the code?
For example when the variable is declared in app.properties i call it this way : @Value("${Country}")
 private String Country;

Comment: Yep, that's all you need to do. The properties will be loaded just as if you declared it in your application.properties in your resource folder.

Comment: do you have an example please? you mean i create an external config file and call it the app.properties file?